# Alignment of from ... import ... statements

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import

I right-align my from...import statements like this:

```
import time
import pytz

from django         import forms
from datetime       import datetime
from www.models     import Forum, Thread, Post, ForumUser
```

But PyCharm is giving me the `PEP8: multiple spaces before keyword` warning, pushing me to change the code to this:

```
import time
import pytz

from django import forms
from datetime import datetime
from www.models import Forum, Thread, Post, ForumUser
```

I find the former method more readable, especially when there are a large number of imports.

So my question is, should I go along with PyCharm and use single-spaces there, or is it ok for me to do it the previous way?  And if it is ok to do it my way, how can I disable that warning in PyCharm?

## Update

This is my approach to disabling just the import warning in PyCharm...
[image]

But it is not working.  I feel like there should be something I can enter in the Options list that would do the trick.

Comment: There's never a need to `PEP-8` your code to death. If something makes your code more readable, then that is probably the way to go

Comment: If your program is syntactically correct and your logic is sound, that's all that ultimately matters. Style standards like PEP 8 are just optional guidelines, and it's up to you to decide if you want to follow them. So mash away at that space bar if it makes you happy!

Comment: I use the tab, being automatically converted to spaces.  Sounds good guys!  Now I just need to figure out how to disable only that warning.  I just like to have that little green check at the top of the file editor window.  Makes me feel better to see it when quickly checking my files (if that makes sense :) )

Comment: Part of the rationale for using single spaces is that it takes a way the temptation to constantly reformat the lines if you add or subtract a line later; changing whitespace is a good way to make a diff more complicated than it needs to be. Related, consider how readable those lines really need to be.

Comment: They definitely need to be a little more readable when you have a dozen or more of them floating at the top of the file and you're trying to quickly skim over them.

Comment: I can't upvote @chepner enough. Aligning things may seem like it makes things more readable, but there is a significant maintenance cost. And in my experience, even things that feel horribly unreadable at first become scannable very quickly if you start using them all the time. Don't get me wrong, I know that "Readability counts"! But consistency with the community counts too. "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it. Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch."

Comment: Specific to `import` statements, nobody really "reads" them; you add them (or update them) when you need to use something they provide elsewhere in your code, and then you essentially forget about them. (That's another reason to put them all at the beginning of your code: so you can ignore them *en masse*.)

Comment: It's during a massive refactor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do agree that sometimes sacrificing PEP8 conformance is necessary in the name of readability. I would just disable that pylint warning for the imports.

```
# pylint: disable=bad-whitespace
from django         import forms
from datetime       import datetime
from www.models     import Forum, Thread, Post, ForumUser
# pylint: enable=bad-whitespace
```

This is under the assumption that your import statements do not change, or change very infrequently. Otherwise, like the others said, this would incur a higher-than-necessary maintenance cost, and the diff would get more complicated than needed.

Comment: Is there a way to do it in PyCharm without having to add the # pylint lines to every file?

Comment: @hmcclungiii You mean specify a directive that will apply to the import statement of _every_ file? Perhaps, but not one that I'm aware of. Then again, I am not well versed with PyCharm!

Answer (score 0):

In preferences, go to Editor -> Inspections -> Python then uncheck PEP8 boxes if you want to disable PEP-8 checking

Comment: I don't want to disable all PEP 8 checks, only the one involving the imports.

Comment: Then @coldspeed 's answer is the way to go, I'll leave this here in case someone may want to disable PEP-8 entirely

Comment: I  updated the question, trying to figure out how to just disable the warning for imports, and not disable all PEP 8 checking.